# Socket Select with empty fd set

Tags: c, select, sockets

Suppose you have an fd set which can have zero or more sockets in it. When I try to call select operation on empty fd set, what I get is -1 as the number of fds which are set, meaning error. So what would you suggest to overcome this problem, you might say do not call if empty but I have a loop and any time fd set can hold 0 or more sockets. What is the best approach about this problem? (we are on C programming language)

Comment: Are you calling `select` with its `nfds` argument set to 0?
What platform are you using?

Comment: You might also want to post the code to make our lives a little easier. Raymond Chen may be a gun psychic debugger but some of us prefer to work from hard evidence :-)

Comment: @Hasturkun - yes nfds is 0 and I am on windows

Answer (score 6):

That's not right. You should be able to specify 0 as the number of file descriptors in the set. In fact, that's how I remember doing timeout code in the early days, using `select` with no descriptors and a timeout value set appropriately.

If it's returning -1, you need to look at `errno` to see what the problem is.

---

Ah, based on your comment, `WSAEINVAL` means WinSock. That explains your problems. It's a hideous beast that should be put out of *our* misery :-)

[This page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141%28VS.85%29.aspx) states that you will get `WSAEINVAL` if the time-out value is not valid or all three descriptor parameters are null. It later states that `FD_ZERO` "initialises the set to the null set". Whether that last snippet means that the parameter is still considered NULL, I don't know. Assuming that your timeout is okay (since it works if you have an FD in one of the sets), that's probably the case.

I do know that Berkeley sockets distinguishes between a NULL FD set (i.e., a NULL pointer) and and empty FD set (a valid pointer with no FDs set) - WinSock may not be that versatile especially since the `nfds` is ignored and included only for compatibility with Berkeley.

I suspect (although I'm not sure) that WinSock is probably expecting you to not do what you're trying to do. It may well just assume that you're doing something wrong and should use `select` only for one or more sockets in one or more FD sets (since the only use for `select` with no FDs is a delay and Windows has plenty of better ways of doing delays).

Comment: In fact it is has been initiated to 0 with FD_ZERO and afterwards I call select but somehow I get -1, and error is WSAEINVAL, but I just use read fd set but I get error, but if I set a socket in it it works...

Comment: @paxdiablo - You are probably right, Windows (the fellow not behaving correctly) just ignores if the fd set is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows, the `select` function ignores the `nfds` argument entirely.
I can't test this currently, but it's possible that an error is returned if all sets are non-NULL but empty.

To work around this, you can either skip the select entirely, or keep a dummy socket to ensure that there is at least one socket in the set at all times.

Comment: You are right nfds is ignored in Windows but, my argument is not NULL is just empty..Windows seems to threat like it is NULL. Bullsh..

Comment: Linux handles this much better than Windows! The call to select() with exactly the same params returns with 0 in Linux.

Also, @Hasturkun, I've tested this on both Windows and Linux - I'll vouch that on Windows it returns -1 (SOCKET_ERROR).

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740141(VS.85).aspx) help. It says WSAEINVAL will be returned if "The time-out value is not valid, or all three descriptor parameters were null." . It's obvious you are passing an incorrect timeout value also. So, provide a correct timout value if you want to use with 0 descriptors.

Comment: okay in fact, as you stated I already read this explanation but my argument s not NULL is empty...

Comment: What are you passing for timeout?

Comment: See, In my understanding select call expects that atleast one of the three descriptor sets should have a value or the timeout value should be proper else there is no way select can ever come out. Right? If you pass all three descriptor parameters as NULL and also mention a incorrect timeout, then select will just block forever.